# Humble bundles donations system, how does it work?

Tags: javascript, php, logging, paypal

I am wondering how the humble bundles donation system works. https://www.humblebundle.com/

How do they know, at the end of the week, how much money was donated to whom?

I'm thinking on how to recreate this in js+php, but I am struggling to figure out how to track transactions.

Thank you in advance

-Jard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of that data would go in your database.  As each transaction comes through you'd save the payer info, receiver info, transaction info, etc. all together in related tables in the db system.  You can generate your own reports out of that or write apps to pull data and loop through records to distribute funds or whatever you need to do.

As @Adelphia mentioned, to process the actual payments you can use PayPal's API's.  For direct credit cards you'd need to sign up with [Payments Pro](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPWebsitePaymentsPro/).  For PayPal or guest checkout payments (credit card through PayPal's pages without signing in) you can use [Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/gs_expresscheckout/).

I have a [PHP class library for PayPal](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library) that will make all of the API calls very simple for you.

Answer (score 0):

Using something like Paypal's [do_direct_payments API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPDirectPayment/) you can have your users fill out their info on your site and then make the payment with Paypal's API using PHP. Or you can always just use Paypal's built in [tracking tools](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/PaymentDetails_API_Operation/).